# Symfony 2 - Class "Mingle\StandardBundle\Entity\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped superclass

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, bundle

I created a `Product.php` file in my bundle `Mingle\StandardBundle\Entity` like this:

```
<?php

namespace Mingle\StandardBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/*
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */

class Product
{
    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ID
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     */
    protected $name;
    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;
    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;
}
?>
```

In Ubuntu Terminal, at root folder of Symfony project, I typed this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Mingle/StandardBundle/Entity/Product
```

And I encountered problem:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                      
  Class "Mingle\StandardBundle\Entity\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

And I don't know how to solve even after searching. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations have to be placed inside `/** */` comment block, otherwise they are not recognized.

Comment: You are using `/* */` comment block, there should be two asterisks at the start

Comment: Thank you
I got out of that error, but encountered some different problems, I'll search for more solutions